# laravel backpack Relationship Not working sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, laravel-backpack

I'm facing problem according the model relationship  in laravel backpack by usiing sqlsrv connection.
In mysql this is working like a charm, but in sql server not.
Does anyone have solution on this issue?

Comment: Can you include more details please?  I don't know Backpack but I imagine that your question would be too thin for anyone to act on.

Comment: Do you have more details?  As it stands now, I don't think your question is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is due to case sensitive issue. you are using model name in small letters. on local it can support but on server it doesn't work.

for example. 
if you are using:

```
$user = user::all(); (this will work on local but not on the server)
$user = User::All(); (while it should be like this)
```